# Reloading java class while debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

While debugging an eclipse application, I am having message properties(resource bundle) file to store messages for dialogs, progress messages and other UI elements which is not getting updated if any new key-value is added.

> Messages.getString("MSG_SOME_KEY", new String[]{param});

Is there any method to reload the messages file without restarting the debugging session.

As an addition to this, is there any way that method signatures can be updated on the fly basis too.

I have looked for a tool like [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) that works for other environments apart from servers.

Comment: Doesn't JRebel solve the problem for you? It can handle message bundles just fine.

Comment: you need something like hot deployment but I am not sure about JRebel

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, but I think all you need is to make sure that "Build Automatically" is checked under your Project menu.